# A management server design

Tags: architecture

I have to design an application which will be more of a management server. We already have web based applications but they are installed on one off basis. It happens with time that instances of application proliferates. So we are coming up with an idea that the various applications can be managed from one management server. An analogy could be anti virus Softwares in individual m/c and the management server which can monitor the individual instances.

For the management server, all the user management piece will move to the server. Any particular ideas, thoughts on the kind of architecture and data model and anything specific to be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricted in terms of technology/programming language?

If you are not, I would create a [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) service that would be hosted on IIS on a server.